# Are Triggers (Webhooks) available yet in the Notion API?

Tags: notion-api

I see that “webhooks” are on the list of features to be implemented next. I *think* that these are what I would call “triggers”, event notifications that occur when, e.g., a row/page in a Notion database is updated.

I guess I have 2 newbie questions then:

1. Are these “webhooks” the same as what I would refer to as event notifications?
2. Are these available in the current Notion API yet?

I didn’t find anything in the Developer guide suggesting that these have been implemented yet.

Answer (score 1):

No, they aren't. You can find Notion API documentation [here](https://developers.notion.com/reference/intro)